# Google Sheets: Add/Remove users and change editor/viewer based on a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, permissions, sharing

I manage a dashboard that has a lot of different Google Docs, Sheets, etc. There is a team of about 100 individuals and I want to dynamically add/remove them from the files, as well as change editor/viewer of the files based on a master sheet with all of the links (or IDs) of the files.

Here is a sample of the master sheet:
[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OogoaZcZgDKvF5pRDXgWHrkPr9Qnc_5eirHQNgU7R0A/edit#gid=0)

I do not have the ability to use Google Groups, as it is restricted by the Admin of the domain. My research shows that it will need to be an Apps Script, but I do not know enought about coding to write something that will work.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result? And, in your situation, can you use Drive API? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. By the way, I cannot open your provided Spreadsheet. I apologize for this.